# Consuming webservice having WSDL and XSD files

Tags: c#, web-services

We've requested a company to write a webservice that we can use to get some information.They have sent us WSDL and XSD files. Could you please tell me how I can use these files to query data? 
 I can do it easily if I have a link to a webservice. I just provide the link and Visual Studio generates web reference for me. After that I can use that reference just like a normal class. In this case I have no link. Just above mentioned files. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a proxy (add service reference in visual studio) from a wsdl file. You can read about svcutil at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx, but VS2010 allow you to put a wsdl file on adress when adding service reference.

Comment: I looked it up but could not find any option to create a proxy from wsdl in add service reference wizard

Comment: Put on the adress the full path to wsdl file.

Comment: Yeah I got it. I just put the file location in the URL field. Thak you so much

Answer (score 2):

> [VS2010 can't create a web service reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421953/cannot-consume-wsdl-in-vs2010) from some WSDLs. Have
>   to [write custom wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380253/net-web-service-cant-add-service-reference-only-web-reference) for those. OR edit your WSDL in a way so
>   VS can consume it. For example it may be ok for you to remove web
>   service method references for the methods that you are not planning to
>   use if those references create trouble for you.

Unless you're stuck with .NET 2.0, you should not use ASMX web service technology.

You should use "Add Service Reference" and point it to the WSDL on disk. It will create a set of "proxy" classes with methods that you can call just as though it were a "normal" class.

See "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)" for a walkthrough with example.

> Use [WSDL.EXE utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx) to generate a Web Service proxy from WSDL.

e.g.

```
wsdl /language:CS /n:"Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010" http://<Server 
Name>/reportserver/reportservice2010.asmx?wsdl
```

check this for [Creating and Consuming .NET Web Services in 5 Easy Steps Article](http://www.sitepoint.com/net-web-services-5-steps/)  and then [Creating the Web Service Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155134.aspx)

Ref:
[WSDL and consume web service](http://forums.asp.net/t/1080013.aspx/1)
[consume non .NET webservice through WSDL file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/6c69a1db-ae37-4565-8e3b-a6e7de95f2b8)
[How to use a WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302525/how-to-use-a-wsdl)