# Consume service with xml definition (xsd) and service definition (wsdl) in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I need consume service. I have available xsd and wsdl file. For wsdl i use this [How to use a WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302525/how-to-use-a-wsdl) ... but I do not know how correct work with it.

Please can you show me example? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consuming webservice having WSDL and XSD files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753640/consuming-webservice-having-wsdl-and-xsd-files)

Comment: I've tried use service reference in VS but after create client instance, alert error "Additional information: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'TestService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."

Comment: UPDATE: I try set URL in client constructor, but next give me this error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.". How can I fix it ?